# distribution of AR, MA coefficients estimation in ARMA-GARCH models

Tags: time-series, garch, arima

could anyone give me an information about distributions of AR and MA coefficients via estimation?
So, for example, I have ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) model with the same AR(1) and MA(1) parameters estimations. So, I know "mean" for it and std, but what's the distribution of each?

Hope, my question isn't dummy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Normally distributed and that's why the two first moments are sufficient to infer their statistical significance.

Proof are rather technical (and sometimes are not specific to time-series models) and mainly depends of:

- The estimation method employed ( QMLE, Least Squares, Moment, Whittle...)
- The parameter space
- Moment restrictions
- ...

These proofs demonstrate, under assumptions, that estimated parameters are consistent ($\hat{\theta} \rightarrow \theta$) and asymptotic Normal ($\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta)\rightarrow N(0,\sigma)$). This is true even if innovations are not Gaussian distributed.

You can have a look to:

- *A Tour in the Asymptotic Theory of GARCH Estimation* by Christian Francq, Jean-Michel Zakoïan (Handbook of Financial Time Series)